# Angular: Next section shown before previous section hidden - using ng-show

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show, angularjs-ng-transclude

I'm implementing a reusable *step-by-step wizard directive* in angular [based on this example](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-directives-that-communicate). It's working pretty well, but like in the example, I'm using ng-show to hide all steps but the current one. This results in a quick flicker whenever I change steps where both the current and next step is shown simultaneously. **What I can't figure out is how to do away with the flicker and make sure only a single step is shown at any one time.**

**What I've tried:**
My own initial attempt at solving this issue was to change the show/hide-mechanic to use ng-switch but it doesn't work well since the ng-switch-when directive only accepts strings (so I can't populate it automatically with an index). Furthermore, ng-switch-when works through translcusion meaning I would have 2 transclusion directives on a single element which doesn't really make sense.

The wizard-directive as I've currently implemented it looks like this:

````js
// Wizard
// ======
//
// This component implements a wizard-directive and a dependent step-directive
// which together can be used to define a step-by-step wizard with arbitrary
// html in each step.
//
// Ex:
// ```html
// <wizard>
//     <step>
//         <h1>Step one</h1>
//     </step>
//     <step>
//         <h1>Step two</h1>
//     </step>
// </wizard>
// ```
//
angular.module('wizard', [])


// Wizard Directive
// ----------------
//
// The main directive which defines the wizard element. A wizard can contain
// arbitrary html, but will only display a single step-element at a time. The
// directive also defines a couple of ways to navigate the wizard - through
// buttons and bottom "tabs".
//
.directive('wizard', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: $rootScope.templateBasePath + '/components/wizard/wizard.html',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            // Initialize the array of steps. This will be filled by any child
            // steps added to the wizard.
            var steps = $scope.steps = [];

            // Search through the wizard to find what step is currently visible.
            function getCurrentStepIndex() {
                var index;
                angular.forEach(steps, function(step, i) {
                    if (step.selected) {
                        index = i;
                        // End early when the selected step is found.
                        return;
                    }
                });
                return index;
            }

            // Make the imagePath available to the template.
            $scope.imagePath = $rootScope.imagePath;

            // Move to the next step in the wizard.
            $scope.next = function () {
                var index = getCurrentStepIndex();
                if (index < steps.length - 1) {
                    steps[index].selected = false;
                    steps[index+1].selected = true;
                }
            };

            // Move to the previous step of the wizard.
            $scope.previous = function () {
                var index = getCurrentStepIndex();
                if (index > 0) {
                    steps[index].selected = false;
                    steps[index-1].selected = true;
                }
            };

            // Select a given step in the wizard.
            $scope.select = function(step) {
                angular.forEach(steps, function(step) {
                    step.selected = false;
                });
                step.selected = true;
            };

            $scope.onFirstStep = function() {
                return getCurrentStepIndex() === 0;
            }

            $scope.onLastStep = function() {
                return getCurrentStepIndex() === steps.length - 1;
            }

            // Called by the step directive to add itself to the wizard.
            this.addStep = function(step) {
                // Select the first step when added.
                if (steps.length === 0) {
                    $scope.select(step);
                }
                // Add the step to the step list.
                steps.push(step);
            };
        }
    };
})

// Step Directive
// --------------
//
// The Step Directive defines a section of code which constitues a distinct step
// in the overall goal of the wizard. The directive can only exist as a direct
// child of a wizard-tag.
//
.directive('step', function() {
    return {
        require: '^wizard', // require a wizard parent
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<div class="wizard__step ng-hide" ng-show="selected"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, wizardCtrl, transclude) {
            // Add itself to the wizard's list of steps.
            wizardCtrl.addStep(scope);

            // Make the wizard scope available under "wizard" in the transcluded
            // html scope.
            scope.wizard = scope.$parent.$parent;

            // Transclude the tag content in order to set the scope. This allows
            // the content to access the wizard's next() and previous() functions.
            var transDiv = angular.element(element).find('.wizard__step');
            transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                transDiv.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});
````

The corresponding wizard template looks like so:

```html
<div class="wizard" tabindex="1">
    <div class="wizard__display">
        <div class="wizard__previous" ng-click="previous()"><div class="guideBack" ng-hide="onFirstStep()"></div></div>
        <div class="wizard__content" ng-transclude></div>
        <div class="wizard__next" ng-click="next()"><div class="guideNext" ng-hide="onLastStep()"></div></div>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav wizard__tabs">
        <li ng-repeat="step in steps" ng-click="select(step)" ng-class="{active:step.selected}"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was making it unnecessarily difficult for myself by focusing all my attention on making it work with ng-show or ng-switch. The problem is eliminated quickly if you just perform the showing and hiding manually through jqlite/jquery. After some refactoring, the wizard-code looks like this:

````
// Wizard
// ======
//
// This component implements a wizard-directive and a dependent step-directive
// which together can be used to define a step-by-step wizard with arbitrary
// html in each step.
//
// Ex:
// ```html
// <wizard>
//     <step>
//         <h1>Step one</h1>
//     </step>
//     <step>
//         <h1>Step two</h1>
//     </step>
// </wizard>
// ```
//
angular.module('ssbbtip.wizard', [])


// Wizard Directive
// ----------------
//
// The main directive which defines the wizard element. A wizard can contain
// arbitrary html, but will only display a single step-element at a time. The
// directive also defines a couple of ways to navigate the wizard - through
// buttons, bottom breadcrumbs and keyboard arrow keys.
//
.directive('wizard', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: $rootScope.templateBasePath + '/components/wizard/wizard.html',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            // Initialize the array of steps. This will be filled by any child
            // steps added to the wizard.
            var steps = $scope.steps = [],
                // currentStep is the shadow variable supporting the
                // `$scope.currentStep` property.
                currentStep = 0;

            // This utility function will adjust a value to fit inside the
            // specified range inclusively.
            function clampToRange(min, max, value) {
                // Make sure the max is at least as big as the min.
                max = (min > max) ? min : max;

                if (value < min) {
                    return min;
                } else if (value > max) {
                    return max;
                } else {
                    return value;
                }
            }


            // This property specifies the currently visible step in the wizard.
            Object.defineProperty($scope, 'currentStep', {
                enumerable: true,
                configurable: false,
                get: function () { return currentStep; },
                set: function (value) {
                    if (value && typeof(value) === 'number') {
                        currentStep = clampToRange(0, steps.length-1, value);
                    } else {
                        currentStep = 0;
                    }
                }
            });

            // Make the imagePath available to the template.
            $scope.imagePath = $rootScope.imagePath;

            // Handle keyboard events on the wizard to allow navigation by
            // keyboard arrows.
            $scope.onKeydown = function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log(event);
                switch (event.which) {
                    case 37: // left arrow
                    case 38: // up arrow
                        $scope.previous();
                        break;
                    case 39: // right arrow
                    case 40: // down arrow
                    case 32: // space bar
                        $scope.next();
                        break;
                }
            };

            // Move to the next step in the wizard.
            $scope.next = function () {
                $scope.currentStep = $scope.currentStep + 1;
            };

            // Move to the previous step of the wizard.
            $scope.previous = function () {
                $scope.currentStep = $scope.currentStep - 1;
            };

            $scope.onFirstStep = function() {
                return $scope.currentStep === 0;
            };

            $scope.onLastStep = function() {
                return $scope.currentStep === steps.length - 1;
            };

            // Called by the step directive to add itself to the wizard.
            this.addStep = function (step) {
                steps.push(step);
            };

            // This watches the `$scope.currentStep` property and updates the UI
            // accordingly.
            $scope.$watch(function () {
                return $scope.currentStep;
            }, function (newValue, oldValue) {
                $element.find('step .wizard__step').eq(oldValue).addClass('ng-hide');
                $element.find('step .wizard__step').eq(newValue).removeClass('ng-hide');
            });
        }
    };
})

// Step Directive
// --------------
//
// The Step Directive defines a section of code which constitues a distinct step
// in the overall goal of the wizard. The directive can only exist as a direct
// child of a wizard-tag.
//
.directive('step', function() {
    return {
        require: '^wizard', // require a wizard parent
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        scope: true,
        template: '<div class="wizard__step ng-hide"></div>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, wizardCtrl, transclude) {
            // Add itself to the wizard's list of steps.
            wizardCtrl.addStep(scope);

            // Make the wizard scope available under "wizard" in the transcluded
            // html scope.
            scope.wizard = scope.$parent.$parent;

            // Transclude the tag content manually in order to set the scope.
            // This allows the content to access the `wizard.next()` and
            // `wizard.previous()` functions.
            var transDiv = angular.element(element).find('.wizard__step');
            transclude(scope, function (clone) {
                transDiv.append(clone);
            });
        }
    };
});
````

and the template:

```
 <div class="wizard" tabindex="1" ng-keydown="onKeydown($event)">
     <!-- tabindex 1 is needed to make the div selectable in order to capture keydown -->
     <div class="wizard__display">
         <div class="wizard__previous" ng-click="previous()"><div class="guideBack" ng-hide="onFirstStep()"></div></div>
         <div class="wizard__content" ng-transclude></div>
         <div class="wizard__next" ng-click="next()"><div class="guideNext" ng-hide="onLastStep()"></div></div>
     </div>
     <ul class="nav wizard__tabs">
         <li ng-repeat="step in steps track by $index" ng-click="currentStep = $index" ng-class="{active: currentStep === $index}"></li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```